# JavaScript download document with $window.open in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer

Within my AngularJS application I want to download a (dynamically generated) document.

In my controller I have

```
$window.open(url, "_blank");
```

This works perfectly in Chrome and in Firefox. However the behavious in IE (version 11) is different -> I get the file also downloaded but IE redirects the user to the home state/screen (so the user needs to navigate one step backwards to the last state/screen where he actually triggered the download)!?

What could be the solution here?

Thx